# How do I find and replace a character in filenames in Windows 7 using Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, rename, filenames, find-and-replace

I want to replace all the underscore characters (`_`) with a space () in a filename.

How can I do this quickly, when I have lots of `_` characters to replace?

Comment: As the answers are indicating, there /is/ no way to do this in Explorer.  You need a script or a batch file renamer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

vbScript should do it for you. 
Create a file called "rename_underscores.vbs" containing the following.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("c:\test\")

For Each File In Folder.Files
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile,"_"," ")
    if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then 
        File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
    end if

Next
```

Make sure the folder name is correct. (In the example, I've used c:\test)
And then double click your file to do the renaming.

Comment: Note that the same works with folders, using 'Folder.SubFolders' instead of 'Folder.Files'.

Comment: working perfectly, just need to take care of the path. +1 thanks

Answer (score 13):

**Edit:** In Windows 10 and 11, it's now possible to do this ([and much more](https://www.howtogeek.com/705534/how-to-easily-batch-rename-files-on-windows-10/)) directly in Explorer using the [PowerRename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename) extension from Microsoft's free PowerToys package. PowerToys has [lots of other great extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/), too. Unfortunately, it's not available for Windows 7--but perhaps you've upgraded your OS since 2010?  ;-)

---

As others have mentioned, there is no way to do exactly what you want without using a script or batch file.  For instance, in PowerShell you can do what you want quite easily:

```
cd "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\MyDirectory"

# by default, -replace is case-insensitive (equivalent to -ireplace)
# for case-sensitive, use -creplace
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_"," " }
```

Just be sure to replace "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\MyDirectory" with the path to your directory.

For more detail and other options, including some things you *can* do using just Explorer, see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: That is really nice, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using a 3rd party tool like [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php). It's free and it has an installer less than 1 MB.

Comment: What if the file name is "this_is_a_test.ext"?

Comment: Bulk Rename Utility is a GREAT applications. Its very versatile and i don't think you can achieve the same with Explorer.

Comment: The dos command would be a little more complicated than that. I'll mock one up.

Comment: i think the answer re the Bulk Rename Utility app on here is more informative https://superuser.com/questions/455096/how-do-you-quickly-remove-underscores-from-folder-names

Comment: After so many years it's still an AWESOME application. Wish I would have found it sooner.

Comment: Bulk Rename Utility have tons of options.

Answer (score 3):

This is within the realms of a dos bat file. Create a bat file (New->Text file, rename extension to .bat) then copy the blue sections below into it.

I'll split it into sections and explain what it's doing.

---

Print the current state of the directory for comparison later

```
dir /b
```

List the files in the directory, then for all the ones that contain
an underscore and end in .txt, call ProcessFile on them.

```
for %%f in (*_*.txt) do call :ProcessFile "%%f"
goto :finished
```

The syntax "str=%str:x=y%" replaces instances of x with y.
In this case, we're replacing "_" with nothing

```
:ProcessFile
set str=%1
rename %1 %str:_=%
goto :eof
```

That's it!

Now it just prints what was changed so we can confirm it's working as expected;

```
:finished
echo ----
dir /b
```

Results (Not part of the bat file)

```
baz_ing.txt
big_rawr.foo
foo_bar.txt
multiple_underscores_test.txt
----
bazing.txt
big_rawr.foo
foobar.txt
multipleunderscorestest.txt
```

Comment: I had to change `for %%f in (*_*.txt) do call :ProcessFile %%f` to `for %%f in (*_*.txt) do call :ProcessFile "%%f"` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [my batch rename ruby script](https://github.com/codism15/rwin/blob/master/bren.rb). I haven't used other batch renaming tools but I think my script is very easy to use and very versatile. Here is the command for your case:

```
ruby bren.rb *_* "_/ "
```

I have setup my windows environment in such a way bren.rb can be executed as an executable from any directory.

Answer (score 1):

Windows-based renaming tool, the most powerful there is, and it's free.
http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explicitly answer the question ('.. in Explorer'), but I found the most useful software to do this was **[Adobe Bridge](http://www.adobe.com/au/products/bridge.html)** (Free)

1. Select all files in Bridge
2. Right click > Batch Rename

Added bonus: Supports Regex!

[image: Screen Shot]